# How to merge these queries into 1 using subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

```
 Select * from HotelPerson 
 Where RoomID IN (select ID from HotelRoom Where BookingID = 36 )

 Select * from HotelCancelationPolicy 
 Where RoomID IN (select ID from HotelRoom Where BookingID = 36 )
```

How can I merge these both queries into 1 query ?

Comment: I assume you want the results of both queries in a single row?  Just INNER JOIN on the `RoomID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you all the columns from both tables in one table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM HotelPerson A, HotelCancelationPolicy B
WHERE A.RoomID = B.RoomID
AND A.RoomID IN (SELECT ID FROM HotelRoom WHERE BookingID = 36)
```

Comment: Argh, don't use impliciit joins with `WHERE` clauses, use explicit joins.  That syntax is dramatically out-of-date

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` to Get Distinct elements or `UNION ALL`  for all rows from both tables

```
 Select * from HotelPerson 
 Where RoomID IN (select ID from HotelRoom Where BookingID = 36 )
 UNION ALL
 Select * from HotelCancelationPolicy 
 Where RoomID IN (select ID from HotelRoom Where BookingID = 36 )
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but that's a huge (and flawed) assumption that their table structures are identical; otherwise, the UNION will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to join the two tables:

```
    select * 
      from HotelPerson hp
inner join HotelCancelationPolicy hcp
        on hp.RoomId = hcp.RoomId
     where hp.RoomID IN (select ID 
                           from HotelRoom 
                          where BookingID = 36 )
```