# Postgres how can I merge 2 separate select queries into 1

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I am using postgres 9.4 and I would like to merge 2 separate queries into one statement. I been looking at this [How to merge these queries into 1 using subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455607/how-to-merge-these-queries-into-1-using-subquery) post but still can't figure out how to work it. These 2 queries do work independently. Here they are

```
# 1:  select * from votes v where v.user_id=32 and v.stream_id=130;

#2: select city,state,post,created_on,votes,id as Voted from streams 
where latitudes >=28.0363 AND 28.9059>= latitudes  order by votes desc limit 5 ;
```

I would like query #2 to be limited by 5, however I don't want query #1 to be included in that limit so that up to 6 rows could be returned in total. This works like a suggestion engine where query #1 has a main thread and query #2 gives up to 5 different suggestions however they are obviously located in a different table.

Comment: Can you add a briefly explanation on how the two queries are related. (An Example would be great)

Comment: The queries do not return a consistent result set schema.  If they did, you could use a union.  Are you trying to join the tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having no model and data I simulated this problem with dummies of both in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5570c/2).

```
CREATE TABLE votes
(
   id smallint
   , user_id smallint
);

CREATE TABLE streams
(
   id smallint
   , foo boolean
);

INSERT INTO votes
VALUES (1, 42), (2, 32), (3, 17), (4, 37), (5, 73), (6, 69), (7, 21), (8, 18), (9, 11), (10, 15), (11, 28);

INSERT INTO streams
VALUES (1, true), (2, true), (3, true), (4, true), (5, true), (6, true), (7, false), (8, false), (9, false), (10, false), (11, false);

SELECT
  id
FROM
  (SELECT id, 1 AS sort FROM votes WHERE user_id = 32) AS query_1
  FULL JOIN (SELECT id FROM streams WHERE NOT foo) AS query_2 USING (id)
ORDER BY
  sort 
LIMIT 6;
```

Also I have to point out, that this isn't my work entirely, but an adaptation of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969038/mysql-order-query-and-display-one-random-row-at-the-top/34969779#34969779) I came across the other day. Maybe this is an approach here too.

So, what's going on? Column `id` stands for any column your tables and sub-queries will have in common. `votes.user_id` I made to have sth. to select in the one sub-query and `streams.foo` in the other.

As you demanded to have 6 rows at the most I used the limit clause twice. First in the sub-query just in case there is a huge amount of rows in your table you don't want to select and again in the outer query to finally restrict the number of rows. Fiddle about a little on the two limits and toggle `WHERE foo` and `WHERE NOT foo` and you see why.

In the first sub-query I added a sort column like it is done in that answer. That's because I guess you want the result of the first sub-query always on top too.

Comment: That was perfect thanks a lot just tried it and it worked